# KEIL uVision 4 problems

Tags: c, microcontroller, keil

I'm using Keil uVision V4.72.9.0, but I can't start the debugging session, because I get this message:

"EVALUATION MODE
Running with Code Size Limit: 2K"

What should I do? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evaluation version has limitations to get people to purchase the product.

If you believe you have the full version, you probably need to enter a license key somewhere to unlock it.

If you don't have a key, you must get one from your employer/school/whoever has you using it, purchase one, or pick a different IDE.

If you believe your code size to be under 2k, there might be something else wrong.  Or the debugger might also be disabled in the evaluation version.  Look up exactly what the limitations of the evaluation version are.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation versions are limited to X (2 in your case) KB of code. Try enabling maximum optimizations for size. Ensure you are using the "best" compiler settings, something that might require some experimentations.

I assume you are using their 8051 compiler. The evaluation version from IAR supports full sizes for 30 days, or 4KB code.